# Is there a way to run GPGPU code while using integrated graphics?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, cuda

Occasionally I run CUDA code, and when I do, the screen goes completely dead for the duration of the computation (since the GPU is preoccupied). It would be amazing if I could switch to using integrated graphics during that time, so that my computer is still usable while the computation is running. Otherwise, I just end up staring at a blank screen, silently hoping that the computation will finish before the RegEdit key timer for killing the GPU clocks out and destroys all my work.

This appears to be [possible on Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75250/is-there-a-way-to-dedicate-the-discrete-graphic-card-to-cuda-on-a-macbook-pro) and [on Linux](http://osdf.github.io/blog/intel-integrated-graphics-dedicated-gpu-for-cuda-and-ubuntu-1310.html). Is this possible on Windows?

#### What I tried:

I am running Windows 7 64-bit. I first disabled the graphics card in "Computer Management", like so:

[image]

This forces the computer to switch to integrated graphics.

After this, I tried running a CUDA executable, but it doesn't appear to work (presumably since the GPU is disabled).

How can I get around this?

Comment: CUDA = nvidia, so running it on an integrated GPU (which I can't see in your picture) doesn't work.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes, I know that. Perhaps I didn't make myself clear, although I thought the question phrasing was clear enough: I want to run a CUDA script on the GPU, and run the Windows GUI on the integrated graphics. Does that make more sense?